# Is there a Python function where I can get the Series title group together in 1 record?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Is there a Python function where I can get the Series title group together in 1 record? I would like to remove the additional extensions from the series name.

Title

1.Evening Edition 16 March 2022 (Part 6)

2.Evening Edition 17/01/2022

3.Evening Edition 30 Nov 2021 (Part 1)

4.Winter Olympic Games 2022: Daily Highlights Day 13 Part 2

5.Winter Olympic Games 2022: Daily Highlights Day 15 Part 2

***The result that I'm looking for is like this:***

Title

1.Evening Edition

2.Winter Olympic Games 2022

Comment: Are you using PySpark? What have you tried?

Comment: How do you know where does the _title_ that you are looking for start and where it ends?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: line 4 and 5 should match over `Winter Olympic Games 2022: Daily Highlights Day 1`. Your current logic is flawed

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is to have the longest possible common substring.
In order to do that you can do the following:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

title1= "something Evening Edition something else"
title2 = "Evening Edition 30 Nov 2021 (Part 1)"

clean_title = SequenceMatcher(None, title1, title2).find_longest_match()
```

This will give you 'Evening Edition', for this case but it will give you 'Winter Olympic Games 2022: Daily Highlights' for the second case. I am not sure if this will work for you, but without additional information about the data it is very trick to do something else.

Maybe you will find something better for your use case here, https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#.